# How can I print each detail from Gelocation Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, geolocation

I am trying to retrieve my city visitor from my website using codeigniter

Here is code to show city

```
$city = $this->geolocation->get_city();
```

Here the output from geolocation is like

```
array(11) { ["statusCode"]=>string(2) "OK" ["statusMessage"]=> string(0) "" ["ipAddress"]=> string(12) "202.60.21.15" ["countryCode"]=> string(2) "ID" ["countryName"]=> string(9) "Indonesia" ["regionName"]=> string(10) "Jawa Timur" ["cityName"]=> string(11) "Pacarkeling" ["zipCode"]=> string(5) "60132" ["latitude"]=> string(6) "-7.258" ["longitude"]=> string(7) "112.758" ["timeZone"]=> string(6) "+07:00" } OK202.67.41.25IDIndonesiaJawa
```

I am using

```
$cities = json_decode($city, true);
foreach ($cities as $c) {               
   echo $c;
}
```

and the output is like this

```
OK202.67.01.25IDIndonesiaJawa TimurPacarkeling60132-7.258112.758+07:00
```

How can I get each data from the output? I want to print each data from Geolocation library in Codeingiter like

```
Your Visitor Country : Indonesia
Your IP Visitor : 202.67.01.25
Your City Name : Pacarkeling
```

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking for the keys of the array? If so, you can do something like this:

```
$city = $this->geolocation->get_city();
$city_info = json_decode($city, true);

foreach ($city_info as $key=>$value) {
    echo 'Your ' . $key . ' : ' . $value . '<br>'; 
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it's work. But, I'm sorry maybe my question was not complete, I mean How if only show City Name.. Thanks

Comment: `$city_info['cityName']`

I think you should give a look to the documentation to clear up some basic concepts [link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).